# blackberry offline web app prompts about network being unavailable

Tags: html, blackberry, offline, web

I'm building a website that uses the html5 cache manifest for offline functionality. It's targeted for blackberry OS6 and up (webkit based browsers).

My problem is that when I turn 3g / wireless off in the simulator (using blackberry 9800) I get constant prompts about every cached item I click.

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/q5qHK.png error

When I click yes it loads the item.  When I click no it complains about the radio signal being too low.

Is there a way to make this dialog go away?  It seems to me that if you're offline, and you have cached content, you want to go ahead and load it.

Comment: Are you sure your stuff is actually in the application cache?  These dialogues seem to imply it's just serving stuff from your browser cache instead.  Is the manifest file definitely getting fetched twice in your server logs (the request pattern should be files for current page -> manifest -> all files in manifest -> manifest again)?